# Python - 2 grouphs of alphanumeric expressions in a sentence

Tags: python, search, expression

How can I solve the following problem? Why is my search not giving me the right output?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njj28.png)

Please find below my code, namely re.search code:

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"^\w \w", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One")) # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) # False
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,
Alexandra

Here it is my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz7iz.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want exactly two such groups.

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.findall(r"\w+|\d+", text)

  return len(result) == 2
```

if you want 2 and more, just change return len(result) == 2 to return len(result) >= 2

Answer (score 0):

```python3
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
    return len(re.findall(r"\w+\s+\w+", text)) > 0
```

\w+ will match a group and then \s+ will match white spaces and then \w+ will match another group, we want this to happen atleast once.